# Can we change the direction of light by electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

As we know light is an EM wave.
So there is a changing electric field and a changing magnetic field in perpendicular direction of the electric field, So can we use an additional electric field to change the direction of the net electric field and thus the direction of EM wave?

Comment: Yes, we can! And it is a called a phased array antenna, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array

Comment: @hyportnex A phased array antenna uses discrete phase modulators, not an electric field, to adjust the phase.

Comment: @JohnDoty a phased array antenna may or may not use discrete phase modulators (depending on the meaning of the word "discrete") but the resulting coherent interference pattern, coherent with an existing wave will change the direction of the latter.

Comment: @hyportnex Can you cite any example of a phased array antenna with phase modulated by a common electric field?

Comment: @JohnDoty in the old days, before ferrites became cheap enough, almost everybody used varactor controlled phase shifters, that would qualify electric field controlled phase modulation but that is not what I was talking about; that is what you were talking about. Let me repeat Junaid's original question for your convenience: "can we use an additional electric field to change the direction of the net electric field and thus the direction of EM wave", and that is what I answered by adding a phase coherent wave with its phase coherent electric and magnetic fields added to that of the original.

Comment: @hyportnex I didn't interpret the OP that way at all. I believe he was asking if a *static* field could deflect a light wave.

Comment: @JohnDoty not necessarily a light but any em wave

Comment: @Junaid Well you said "light" in the title. If you go far enough into the gamma ray range that pair production affects the results, the story gets more complicated. But that is beyond the phenomena of classical EM waves.

Answer (score 3):

Not in a vacuum. But with the [Kerr effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_effect), we can adjust the refractive index of a material, which allows us to direct a light beam.

Comment: Why not in vacuum?
If I change the direction of the electric field of em wave by adding another electric field, should the direction of the wave also change?
As the poynting vector is the cross product of E and B?

Comment: @Junaid Well, we don't see it happen in a vacuum. That's one of the many observations that went into classical electromagnetic theory. The way the theory captures this observed fact is that the vacuum electromagnetic wave equation is linear. That means that any sum of solutions is also a solution, so the terms in the sum retain their identity and do not affect each other.